# How to configure the preact dev server to use a different address?

Tags: preact

By default the dev server in a standard preact setup runs either on `http://0.0.0.0:8080` or your current IPv4 address:

```
You can view the application in browser.

Local:            http://0.0.0.0:8080
On Your Network:  http://192.168.2.105:8080
```

Both are not very useful. The `0.0.0.0` is something that cannot serve anything (at least on macOS, where I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in all my browsers (Chrome, Brave, FF, Safari) and the current IP address is dynamic. Additionally, I'd like to use https.

How can I change the address under which the dev server serves the app content?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not preact.config.js, as I thought, but [preact-cli](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/blob/master/README.md#preact-watch), which accepts a number of parameters to configure the webserver:

```
$ preact watch

    --src              Specify source directory  (default src)
    --cwd              A directory to use instead of $PWD  (default .)
    --esm              Builds ES-2015 bundles for your code  (default false)
    --clear            Clear the console (default true)
    --sw               Generate and attach a Service Worker  (default false)
    --babelConfig      Path to custom Babel config (default .babelrc)
    --json             Generate build stats for bundle analysis
    --https            Run server with HTTPS protocol
    --key              Path to PEM key for custom SSL certificate
    --cert             Path to custom SSL certificate
    --cacert           Path to optional CA certificate override
    --prerender        Pre-render static content on first run
    --prerenderUrls    Path to pre-rendered routes config  (default prerender-urls.json)
    --template         Path to custom HTML template (default 'src/template.html')
    --refresh          Enables experimental preact-refresh functionality
    -c, --config       Path to custom CLI config  (default preact.config.js)
    -H, --host         Set server hostname  (default 0.0.0.0)
    -p, --port         Set server port  (default 8080)
    -h, --help         Displays this message
```

With that I could create the proper commands for preact in package.json:

```json
    "scripts": {
        "build": "preact build",
        "dev": "preact watch -H localhost -p 3000 --clear false",
    },
```

Comment: Both the CLI flag and `preact.config.js` would work just as well, FWIW. `0.0.0.0` essentially means "all addresses on this machine", so any address should work just fine. That's odd though, MacOS certainly used to support `0.0.0.0` just fine. We display `localhost` in place of that on Windows as historically it was the only one that had issues there. Might need to switch that to `!linux`.

Comment: It's pretty unusual to use `0.0.0.0`. This was the first time I saw it being used. However, my main problem was that I missed that single link to the `preact-cli` options as I was looking for a documentation that explains `preact.config.json`. Btw. `localhost` didn't work either with default values. Only after I set it as host in the `watch` command things started to work finally.